# Hiding gizmo and description in 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I need a clean window for the preview.

Can I hide the gizmo and the description on the 3D view?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Viewport Navigation Gizmo:

[image]

Alternatively if you want to just hide the gizmo but not the other navigation buttons:

[image]

### Text Overlay:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Shift + Alt + Z to hide/unhide viewport info texts, grid and coordinate axes. Ctrl + ` to hide/unhide navigation gizmo and Ctrl + Alt + Space to hide every UI element for fullscreen preview of the scene. I use these shortcuts a lot for clutter free viewport render previews.[image][image][image]

Comment: Thank you for complementing the answer.